# How to build the response for curl request?

Tags: php, curl

I'll appreciate anyone who can help me out here. Here's the case:
I am using the following code in a.php to pass 3 variables to another web page - b.php.

a.php

```
$title = "some title here";
$password = "qwertyu";
$button_id = "87";
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
   CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.example.com/b.php",
   CURLOPT_POST => true,
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('bid' => $button_id, 'pass' => $password, 'title' => $title)
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($httpCode);
```

b.php gets the values, performs certain actions and send notifications to multiple users. at the end of b.php there's a variable that gets the number of users who got the notification (for this example, let's say that the variable gets "487" meaning that the notification was sent successfully to 487 users.

Currently the above code echos "200" which is the http code for OK. However, instead of the http code, I would like to echo the number of users who got the notification, something like: "Your notification has been sent successfully to 487 users."

My question is what I need to do in b.php so it will send back this data to a.php and whether I should add any code to the above code in a.php for that purpose?

Thank you very much in advance.

Ofer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.php` should end with:

```
echo $user_count;
```

In `a.php`, this will be in `$result` because you used `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.